# What does "Primi & imi, ad unum omnes" mean?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

From [A vocabulary English and Latin](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z8FpMU_qiVMC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22primi%20%26%20imi%20ad%20unum%20omnes%22&source=bl&ots=Fx2KkBRd6m&sig=ACfU3U2PnIBcRZWQbOUZpPnWVhlHZ0lgyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix1NX4vtXsAhVJTBoKHVZBAtcQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22primi%20%26%20imi%20ad%20unum%20omnes%22&f=false):

> 67. Vapulabitis indiscriminatim omnes - You all, without discrimination, shall be beaten!

> 68. **Primi & imi, ad unum omnes**

The translation in the book is *"High and low, not one shall escape"*, which seems fairly lax (as many other translations there). But I'm not sure how to understand this sentence (which is probably related to one above him). I have issues with both parts. Not sure whether *primi* and *imi* are nomanitive plural or genitive of something; also *ad unum omnes* is somewhat mysterious for me in this context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Primus* means "first," as you probably know. (Technically it is the superlative of *prior*.)

*Imus* is an alternative form of *infimus*, the superlative of *infer*, so it means "lowest," but also "last."

So I would say *primi et imi* means "the first and the last," but since this may also refer to positions (the ones in first place, the ones in last place), I suppose "the highest and the lowest" also fits.

*Ad unum* is a fixed expression meaning "to the last, to a man, without exception."

So I would translate the whole phrase as:

> The highest and the lowest, no exceptions.